# How to display a checkbox from a database table in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox, symfony-forms

I want to display a database value in a checkbox,  during add and edit time

Here is my code which displays values in combobox

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder->add('role', 'entity', array(
    'class'         => 'DashboardAdminManageUserBundle:role',
    'property'      => 'title',
    'multiple'      => true,
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('g');

    },
    'label'    => 'Role*:',
    'by_reference' => false,
    'required' => false,
    ));



}
```

So how do you display the same values in a Checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [expanded option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#expanded) and set it to true. Take a look at the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#expanded) for more informations.

```
$builder->add('role', 'entity', array(
    'class'    => 'DashboardAdminManageUserBundle:role',
    'property' => 'title',
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'label'    => 'Role*:',
    'required' => false,

    // Add custom html attribute
    'attr'     => array('class' => 'my-class'),
));
```

Then, just need to customize the `.my-class` input CSS.

Comment: it is default check box.. 
and i want dynamic value from database

Comment: It is not clear what do you call dynamic value from database? If you use this configuration all checkbox have a dynamix value which comes from the database (using the title property of the DashboardAdminManageUserBundle:role class).

Comment: pl give me one example for the same

Comment: gelo thanks for help  
but one question 
check box is not display properly how to add css in  checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Select tag, Checkboxes or Radio Buttons field may be rendered as one of several different HTML fields, depending on the expanded and multiple options:

select tag  =>  expanded = false ,multiple = false

select tag (with multiple attribute) => expanded = false, multiple = true

radio buttons  => expanded = true, multiple = false

checkboxes =>  expanded = true, multiple = true

Refer this table for your requirement